# Append elm-ui button to 2nd child of column , type error

Tags: elm, elm-ui

Trying to create a simple Point of Sale in elm similar to image below.

Click a Product (`Input.button`, which understand is of type `Element msg`?) then a record of said button is created in the Order List panel. This is also an `Input.button` and can be removed from the Order panel by clicking.

At the moment my `model` looks like this:

```
type alias Orders =
    { order : Element Msg } -- fully aware this is uppercase 'M', not matching what the column expects

type alias Model =
    { orderlist : List Orders }
```

adding my `model` to `view` .. `column [] [ model.orderlist ]` gives the following error:

> This argument is a list of type:
> List (List Orders)
>
> But `column` needs the 2nd argument to be:
> List (Element msg)

what am I missing here? Any comments or ideas most welcome. Also I'm fully open to going a different direction if it might help me achieve my the goal of creating this POS. TIA :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, it is expected that the 2nd argument would be a `List` of `Element msg`.

But your `model.orderList` gives you a List of a Record `{order: Element Msg}`.

In order to solve you will need to map on the list and extract your `Element Msg`, something like:

```
... column [] (model.orderList |> List.map (\{order} -> order))
```

Comment: Instead of `List.map (\{order} -> order)`, you can write `List.map .order`.